# how to move all js package <script> tags from index.html into a single js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to move my webEngage script into another file, so I can pass it as an entry point in my webpack. Here is what I already have in my index.ejs

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta
   name="viewport"
   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"
 />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- ICONS SPRITE -->
<div style="display: none">
  <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.files.sprites) { for (var spriteFileName in
  htmlWebpackPlugin.files.sprites) { %> <%=
  htmlWebpackPlugin.files.sprites[spriteFileName] %> <% } } %>
</div>
<div id="root"></div>
<noscript>
  scripts is disabled, please enable javascript and try again!
</noscript>

<!-- WebEngage Script -->
<script id="_webengage_script_tag" type="text/javascript">
  var webengage;
  !(function(w, e, b, n, g) {
    function o(e, t) {
      e[t[t.length - 1]] = function() {
        r.__queue.push([t.join('.'), arguments]);
      };
    }
    .
    .
    .
  })(window, document, 'webengage');
</body>
```

I was thinking of declaring an IIFE in a scripts.js file, but it didn't work.
I would appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Am I missing something here?  You could just use JavaScript's import.
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-import/

Comment: Move your code into a js file and make sure to import it in your index.js or whatever your entry point is `import './foo.js'`

Comment: @Dale, it might be as simple as you are seeing it. But I have some problem understanding how I can merge all my imports like hotjar, webengage, tag manager and any other script in a single file and declare only one script tag in my index.html. How must be the closure? Should it be a function or an IIFE?